# Stampings Algorithm in ASP.NET MVC LINQ Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

As the title says, I'am trying to write an algoritm with these conditions:

Each employee has a flextime balance which is initially zero.
If the total time of all stamp ins and stamp outs in a working day exceeds 8 hours, the flexitime balance listed with the prolonged time , and the same principle applies to the deficit.
Flextime balance is listed with all the time stamped on the days that are relieved of work.

If no stamps occurred on a working day then the flextime balance is not affected.

There are two tables im having in the database: NonWorkingDays and Stampings.

NonWorkingDays contains only of one column which is: "Days (DateTime)".

Stampings contains of four columns: "Id (Int) (PK), UserId (Int), Timestamp (DateTime), StampingType (value "in" and value "out")

This is what I wrote so far -

Model:

```
public class FlexModel
{
    public List<User> Users { get; set; }
    public List<Stamping> Stampings { get; set; } 
    public decimal FlexTime { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model Aviato.ViewModel.FlexModel

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h2>Info</h2>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Users[0].UserId)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Users[0].SocialSecurityNumber)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Users[0].FirstName)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Users[0].LastName)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Users[0].EmploymentStartDate)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Users[0].EmploymentEndDate)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Users[0].Password)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Users[0].RoleName)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Users[0].Address1, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Users[0].Address1, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Users[0].Address1, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Users[0].Address2, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Users[0].Address2, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Users[0].Address2, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Users[0].ZipCode, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Users[0].ZipCode, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Users[0].ZipCode, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Users[0].City, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Users[0].City, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Users[0].City, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Users[0].PhoneNumber1, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Users[0].PhoneNumber1, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Users[0].PhoneNumber1, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Users[0].PhoneNumber2, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Users[0].PhoneNumber2, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Users[0].PhoneNumber2, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FlexTime, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FlexTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FlexTime, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Spara" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Controller:

```
        public ActionResult Info()
    {
        var flexModel = new FlexModel();

        var userId = (int)Session["userId"];
        var user = _db.Users.Find(userId);

        var stampIn = _db.Stampings.Where(i => i.StampingType == "in").Where(i => i.User == user).ToList();
        var stampOut = _db.Stampings.Where(i => i.StampingType == "out").Where(i => i.User == user).ToList();

        var workDay = 8;

        if (stampIn.Count == 0)
        {
            return View();
        }

        foreach (var itemIn in stampIn)
        {

        }

        foreach (var itemOut in stampOut)
        {

        }

        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Info(FlexModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            foreach (var item in model.Users)
            {
                _db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }
            _db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

So this is not working for me, I get the value of Flex to display 0.

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is it that's not working?

Comment: Im trying to come up with the idea of how Im supposed to compare these two different timespans to begin with, which I have no idea of...

Comment: I'll have a look in the morning, but can a user have multiple ins and outs per day - e.g in at 8.00am, out at 10.00am, in at 2.00pm, out at 6.00pm? There are lots of other strange things in you code such are there multiple users with the same `userId` (why is `Users` a `List`)?. Why is `userId` in session (as opposed to passing the ID to the `Info` GET method)? Why do you have `ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FlexTime` when you don't have an input for it. And are you wanting the result for a particular date or for all dates?

Comment: Ive changed it to a much more logical code, take a look please.

Comment: Sorry, but its not logical at all, and you haven't answered any of my comments above. The key issues are 1) can a user have multiple ins and outs per day and 2) are you wanting the result for a particular date or for all dates?